# Wrong shape type

Tags: shapefile, polygon, geotools

I am from statistics, and I need to do a fast cartogram.

But I am getting this error from [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/):

```
Error processing record (a):160
PolygonHandler.read() - got shape type 1610612760 but was expecting 5
org.geotools.shapefile.InvalidShapefileException: PolygonHandler.read() - got shape type 1610612760 but was expecting 5
```

**Background:** I have downloaded the map of my country from http://www.gadm.org/, and I have reduced it to 5 regions using QGIS. I can open the shapefile I have created using `readOGR{rgdal}` in R, and I can plot it fine. Only ScapeToad is giving an error, maybe because it is more sensible. I probably did something wrong...

Can someone make sense of that error message?

Comment: its an old GeoTools message - that I'm fairly sure we don't throw anymore (and I'm pretty sure it used to be a warning any way). Is there any more error log? alternatively can you post the shapefile somewhere I can download it

Comment: At first glance it looks like the data is corrupt, 5 is the OGC number for a polygon but the geometry FID/OID/Row 160 has 1610612760 instead. Try re-downloading the data, if the problem persists open it in QGIS/ArcGis and look at #160 - it might not appear in which case it can be removed and the rest of the records should process as normal.